# What would be an alternative to the Reuben Alcalay Hebrew-English Dictionary?

Tags: hebrew, dictionary

I've been looking for a decent copy of the well-known Reuben Alcalay dictionary, at a price that I can live with and in good condition.  Unfortunately, I haven't found much.  So now I'm looking for an alternative.

I'm looking for something to have alongside me whilst learning (primarily written by Acharonim).

I've heard that the Alcalay dictionary is the gold standard for Hebrew reference but what would be a near equivalent?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Shilo dictionary](https://www.judaicapress.com/products/the-comprehensive-shilo-dictionary) isn't as comprehensive as Alcalay's dictionary, but still includes many classical idioms.

Answer (score 0):

I find [*A Comprehensive Etymological Dictionary of the Hebrew Language* by Ernest Klein](https://archive.org/details/AComprehensiveEtymologicalDictionaryOfTheHebrewLanguageErnestKlein1987OCR) to be a good choice.  It is freely available on archive.org, it is quite comprehensive in including words from different eras (early Biblical Hebrew, post-exilic Hebrew, Mishnaic Hebrew, all correctly noted with the definition), and it often makes connections between roots that may not be obvious.